# A famous rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus

Given the pictures below, who am I?
Answer with the significance of each picture

[image]

Comment: In what sense is this a "rebus" puzzle?

Comment: @puppetsock Click on the rebus tag for more details

Comment: In other words, it's *not* a rebus. Yeah, thanks.

Comment: @puppetsock I don’t see what you mean

Comment: Any random puzzle with pictures in it is not a rebus.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, @puppetsock. I see what you mean by a rebus in its literal sense and hence a difference in opinion. The tag description fits fine for this usage, if you do believe otherwise, consider placing an edit to the tag (and this post if you may) and see if it gets accepted by the peers of Puzzling.SE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it

> Benedict Cumberbatch?

Egg:

> Eggs Benedict is a breakfast dish (Thanks @CG)

Suit:

> BC played Sherlock Holmes, who wears the same kind of tweed suit

Dragon:

> He also motion captured the dragon Smaug in the Hobbit

Clock:

> Maybe something to do with Doctor Strange, again played by BC, and his time manipulating abilities

Cucumber:

> Benedict **Cucumber**batch :D

Comment: Rttf Orarqvpg vf n oernxsnfg qvfu. I'm guessing that's the link.

Comment: https://s3-media0.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/lhGOluycLEQwBImloLopOg/348s.jpg